# use spacy word vectors in torchtext

Tags: python, spacy, word-embedding, torchtext

spacy provides german word vectors [spacy model de](https://spacy.io/models/de), so I want to make use of them with pytorch and torchtext.

```
word_vectors = torch.FloatTensor(spacy_de.vocab.vectors.data)
emb = nn.Embedding.from_pretrained(word_vectors)
TEXT = data.Field(tokenize=tokenize,lower=True)
TEXT.build_vocab(vocab,vectors=word_vectors)
```

However when i try to build `TEXT.build_vocab` I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Got input vectors of type <class 'torch.Tensor'>, expected str or Vectors object
```

So i looked  `Vector` up in the torchtext documentation [torchtext vectors](https://torchtext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vocab.html#vectors) and it seems I need to load them first. Is there a solution where I do not have to save the spacy word vectors to a file first? And if not, what is the correct way to save spacy word vectors that later I can load them ?